# Enable forced vectorisation of for-loop

Tags: c, multithreading, optimization, openmp, vectorization

I have a loop which is inside a parallel construct which goes like this

```
# pragma omp parallel ... //directives
{
// other loops ....
#pragma omp for
    for (i=1; i<=nx; i++) for (j=1; j<=ny; j++) for (k=1; k<=nz; k++)
    {
         p_sparse_s[i][j][k] = RLL[i][j][k] + (riri_sparse2 / noemer_sparse) * p_sparse_s[i][j][k];
    }
// other loops ....
}
```

On inspecting it seems this loop is not being vectorized because of assumed dependency. On further inspecting with dependence analysis there is no dependency ( as evident from the code ). How should the directive be changed so that I tell the compiler to enforce vectorization?

P.S. If i use the ivdep directive then also the compiler is not vectorising the loop.

```
# pragma omp parallel ... //directives
{
// other loops ....
#pragma ivdep
#pragma omp for
    for (i=1; i<=nx; i++) for (j=1; j<=ny; j++) for (k=1; k<=nz; k++)
    {
         p_sparse_s[i][j][k] = RLL[i][j][k] + (riri_sparse2 / noemer_sparse) * p_sparse_s[i][j][k];
    }
// other loops ....
}
```

Comment: You could try `#pragma omp simd`. The Intel C++ compiler also supports `#pragma vector` (https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524559), but I don't know how that is with other compilers.

Comment: @qubit where should I actually add the simd directive with the '#pragma omp for' directive or as a separate line.

Comment: In your case you should try it as `#pragma omp for simd`. Just add it to the existing pragma, if that doesn't work I'd try the vector pragma, if you have access to the right compiler that is, I don't believe it's standard.

Comment: You should also consider taking a look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681300/diferences-between-pragmas-simd-and-ivdep-vector-always, they explain the differences between ivdep and simd.

Comment: @Qubit thanks .. simd seems to work properly. Almost halved the time taken in the loop computation. Maybe you would like to answer this (related question but with loop dependencies) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51580852/vectorisation-of-for-loop-with-data-dependecy?noredirect=1#comment90130582_51582405

Comment: I'll write an answer to this question first, so that anyone that stumbles upon this post finds the answer. Not to mention your other question appears to be answered?

Comment: Yeah sure. Regarding the other question, in a way yes seems like loop transformations is what I will need but not able to get a grasp of the topic specially the dependence vectors etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `ivdep` pragma does not force the compiler to vectorize a loop, in order to achieve that one should instead use the `simd` pragma.

```
#pragma omp simd
```

In your case, you can simply append it to the for as `#pragma omp for simd`. Note that it is advised that you add some hints to the simd pragma, such as the specific type of vectorization you had in mind (the available clauses can be found here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524530).

Comment: i inspected a bit fiurther, it seems writing `#pragma omp for simd` is only vectorising the outer loop. Changing it to `#pragma omp for simd collapse(3)` deteriorates the problem (elogates compute time) because of memory acccess. Any pointers what I am doing wrong

Comment: `#pragma omp simd` is different from `#pragma simd`! The former is an independent standard and only *allows* vectorization. The latter seems to be intel specific and actually force vectorization. The answer you linked discussed only the latter.

Comment: @Zulan Ah, you are correct, I missed that. I believe `#pragma simd`is deprecated anyway (in the newest versions) and only `#pragma omp simd` remains. I'll remove that part of the answer, it's not particularly relevant anyway.

Comment: @datapanda You only show a single for loop that does not appear to be nested in your example, if you have nested for loops that you can not collapse trivially I would suggest only using vectorization on the innermost loop. Note that if that loop has nontrivial memory access vectorization doesn't make sense, it's only reasonabe when the data can be loaded with a single instruction (i.e. you load a contiguous block of data).

Comment: @qubit the example loop shown above is a nested for loop of `i, j, k`. I didn't get what you meant. (well the second part regarding contiguous nature, i do understand).

Comment: @datapanda Well, that's what I get for answering in a hurry, you are, of course, correct. Try only vectorizing the innermost loop (`k`).